# memory issue when making multiple post requests at once with large media file in node

Tags: file-upload, request, bluebird, large-data

I am trying to upload large media file with `request` and `bluebird`. Here is my code

```
 const options = {
   url: 'someuploadurl',
   method: 'POST',
   json: true, 
   headers: { 
   Authorization: 'Bearer access_token', 
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
   },
   formData: {
     file: {
      value: mediaData, 
      options: { filename: 'myMedia.mp4', contentType: 'video/mp4'}
     }
   }  
 }

const uploadFunction = (options) => {
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if(error){
        reject(error)
      }
      resolve(body)
    })
  }).then(console.log).catch(console.log)
}

const sendMultipleRequests = () => {
  const totalRequests = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
  // make 8 requests at once
  blueBird.map(totalRequests, () => {
    uploadFunction(options)
  })
}
```

This code is working when `totalRequests.length` is 3 or less. 
Also code works when all media files are small(< 2-3mb) but when media files are large(> 30mb), it breaks the code gives error `Socket hang up`.

I saw the memory usage of my system, as request increases memory usage increases, the process takes the whole ram memory and then code crashes with the error.

Please guide me to make this code work or you can share any other way to upload media which will work in that scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit the number of the concurrent requests depending on how much the running system can handle.

```
blueBird.map(totalRequests, () => uploadFunction(options), { concurrency: 3 })
```